# Adverbial form of "pixel"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, computing

I know that the verbal and verbal-noun forms of *pixel* are *pixelate* and *pixelation*, respectively, but what is/are the adverbial form(s) of the term?

I looked on the OED, ODO, Merriam-Webster Online, and even Dictionary.com, and no such forms were listed. Is there even an adverbial form? If not, what would you suggest I use?

Some ideas I’ve thought of have been

- *pixelly*
- *pixally*
- *pixelatedly*

Here’s an example sentence (just made up on the spot, so don’t try to look it up or anything):

> The colour of the object depicted on this LCD television screen is
>   red, green, and blue **[insert adverb here]**, but from proper viewing
>   distance the colours produce a bright purple.

Comment: Use in what sort of ways? 'Pixelated' is available.

Comment: Adjectivally, your picture might be *pixelated*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: *Pixelated* is an **adjective** / **verb**, not an adverb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's not an adverb, though! x_x

Comment: I just realised my question in the body was different than the question in the title. I'm such an idiot... X_x

Comment: Can you  give an example sentence where this adverbial form might be useful?

Comment: @Hellion: Sure, no problem: `The colour of the object depicted on this LCD television screen is red, green, and blue [insert adverb here], but from proper viewing distance the colours produce a bright purple.`

Comment: I just made that example sentence up on the spot, so don't try to look it up or anything. xD

Comment: Also, I forgot: in the above example, attach the prefix *sub-* before the adverb, of course.

Comment: One would use the workaround 'is made up of red, blue and green pixels ...'. English has lexical gaps.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I can't do a workaround. Besides, that's just putting off a problem for another day. I want to figure it out now. If there **is no** word for it, that's fine. Just say it. But if there **is** a word for it, then I would like to know. If you don't know what it is, but know there is a word for it, that's fine, too. Just tell me. Lol.

Comment: If you're desperate, the 2012 Segen's Medical Dictionary has an entry for [Pixely](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/pixely) but I'm unsure if it's a distinct adverb or just a lesser used alternative adjective to pixelated.  I vaguely recall discussing how gentlemanly is an adjective here earlier despite ending in the -ly suffix  and there are [other words like that](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adverbs.htm) as well...

Comment: I'll say 'There's no such word' (although I'm only about 97% certain). If you can't use a workaround, and as making up nonce words for use in formal contexts is frowned upon by many, the question becomes 'What are _you_ going to do?'

Comment: @tchrist: Regarding your edit: Sure, very often, people don't consider "verbial" a word, but considering "adverbial" is a word, then "verbial" is pretty much already a word. It's just not formally used. Either way, I think that was kind of a cheap edit you made...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the question:

> Is there even an adverbial form? If not, what would you suggest I use?

Edwin Ashworth has replied to both parts of your question in his comment. Yet you don't seem happy with his reply.

> I looked on the OED, ODO, Merriam-Webster Online, and even
>   Dictionary.com and no such forms were listed

So where would Edwin Ashworth (or any of us) look to find the word you want?

Perhaps you could just make it up yourself by adding "ly" to the adjective "pixellated". That would be such a common construction that everyone would know what you mean (if they're ok with "pixel" in the first place).

Otherwise, because "English has lexical gaps" (Edwin Ashworth), there may be no alternative to a workaround.

Comment: This answer was not very constructive. For one, Edwin Ashworth didn't answer my question; he merely first gave an adjective, which isn't what I needed, and then gave a workaround, which I don't want to do **unless**, as I stated in my question details, there is no preëxistent word available. It would have been better to directly answer my question instead of offering a roundabout response. For example, "Either there isn't a word, or I don't know of one; but here is a workaround."

Comment: And two: "So where would Edwin Ashworth (or any of us) look to find the word you want?" Ever hear of other dictionaries? Or maybe historical resources? Perhaps others have heard or read of an alternate form that I *haven't*. This should be quite obvious. Why do you think the `word-requests` tag exists?

Comment: Although the suggestions you listed in the last two paragraphs are definitely good ones. So thank you for that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your offered example sentence, you don’t actually want an adverb here at all.  Rather, you want the corresponding adjective derived from the noun *pixel*. So simply add *‑ed*, either this way:

> The colour of the object depicted on this LCD television screen is red, green, and blue **pixelled**, but from proper viewing distance the colours produce a bright purple.

or this way:

> The color of the object depicted on this LCD television screen is red, green, and blue **pixelled**, but from proper viewing distance the colors produce a bright purple.

or this way:

> The color of the object depicted on this LCD television screen is red, green, and blue **pixeled**, but from proper viewing distance the colors produce a bright purple.

The word is newish, but both useful and used. It has two spellings, as shown in [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pixeled%2Cpixelled&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpixeled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpixelled%3B%2Cc0):

[image: ngram of pixeled, pixelled]

However, I question the very premise behind the example sentence.

The color of each constituent pixel on a television monitor is necessarily one of red, blue, or green, since those are the three available pixel types. When viewed normally, the pixels can combine to produce a signal in [the human vision system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#Color_in_the_human_brain) which is indistinguishable from [monochromatic violet (380–450 nanometers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violet_(color)) through [metamerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism_(color)). Spectral violet at the bottom of the rainbow is a shorter wavelength than blue, so no single pixel on your television can produce it — but metamerism guarantees that you cannot tell the difference.

Indeed, any given pixel can produce only one of three possible colors. It is only through their combination can millions of colors be produced by generating a suitable tristimulous response in the brains of viewers with normal human color vision.

It is also possible that you mean not spectral violet but some combination of red and blue along the [line of purples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_purples). If so, you should make that clear.

Comment: Although I thank you for your explanation of metamerism (seriously, I'm gonna read up on that; I appreciate that a *lot*!), it doesn't really matter. As I said, that was merely an **example** I used. The fact is I *did* need the adverbial form of it, NOT the adjectival form. Both forms could work in this context (even the context in the example sentence), but frankly the adverbial form would work much better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to propose, not a work-around, but a rewrite:

> The object depicted on this LCD television screen is made up of red, green, and
>   blue pixels, but from proper viewing distance the colors produce a
>   bright purple.

Comment: A re-write *is* a workaround. In any case, that's not what I'd be writing about.